# unix command to print till 3rd occurence of "/" in each line

Tags: command

I have one file contains data as follows...

```
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus/?ua=TQ-AUTOCLOSE-REENTER&filterId=089089087087080&dt=1325757272
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus/?ua=TQ-AUTOCLOSE-REENTER&filterId=089089087087080&dt=1873982869
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus/?ua=TQ-BUTTON-DISABLED&sessionType=1&sessionId=4938718&filterId=97462&dt=1354822214604
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus/?ua=TQ-BUTTON-DISABLED&sessionType=1&sessionId=4951063&filterId=95997&dt=1354807593071
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus/?ua=TQ-BUTTON-DISABLED&sessionType=2&sessionId=4957338&filterId=99353&dt=1354752909284
```

How can I get the output that prints till 3rd occurrence of "/" in each line?

Comment: Anything that you have tried ?

Comment: If your input is representative, it would probably be better to instead print everything up to the first `?`, and `awk '{print $1}' FS=?` works nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F/ 'BEGIN{OFS="/";}{print $1,$2,$3}' your_file
```

Answer (score 15):

It's as simple as this - separated by '/', cut fields 1-4:

`cut -d'/' -f1-4`

Example:

```
$ echo /foo/bar/baz/extra | cut -d'/' -f1-4
/foo/bar/baz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's_\(/.*/.*\)/.*_\1_' your-file.txt
```

This is an example:

```
>sed 's_\(/.*/.*\)/.*_\1_' your-file.txt
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut`'s better, but with `sed`:

```
sed 's|/|\n|3;P;d'
```

You might need a literal newline with some `sed`s, though.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -F'/' -anle 'BEGIN{$,="/"} print @{[@F[0..2]]}' file
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus
/tutordashboard/manageTutorLogInStatus
```